# How to round a decimal to the nearest 1/n

Tags: ruby

I want to round a number to the nearest 1/4. For example, if I have `3.21`, I'd round it to `3.25`, or if I have `3.46`, I'd round to `3.50`. I'd like to write a method for this, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `(number / 0.25).round * 0.25`